# msbuild service start/stop

Tags: xml, service, msbuild, batch-file

I have a fairly large msbuild xml script.
I am not that fluent in xml, is there a way to start or stop a windows service in the script without puting the code in a batch file?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following command to start / stop services

```
net start "servicename"
```

or

```
net stop "servicename"
```

or in MSBuild:

```
<Exec Command="net start %(Service.Name)" />
```

Comment: how can this be embedded in an xml?